# How to replace all the same text inside a blocked text in vim?

Tags: vim

How to change this code:

```
    dayHour: {
        sunday: {
          openHour: null,
          closeHour: null,
        },
        monday: {
          openHour: null,
          closeHour: null,
        },
        tuesday: {
          openHour: null,
          closeHour: null,
        },
        wednesday: {
          openHour: null,
          closeHour: null,
        },
        thursday: {
          openHour: null,
          closeHour: null,
        },
        ...
     }
```

to this code :

```
dayHour: {
    sunday: {
      openHour: null,
      closeHour: null,
      openMenu: null,
      closeMenu: null
    },
    monday: {
      openHour: null,
      closeHour: null,
      openMenu: null,
      closeMenu: null
    },
    tuesday: {
      openHour: null,
      closeHour: null,
      openMenu: null,
      closeMenu: null
    },
    wednesday: {
      openHour: null,
      closeHour: null,
      openMenu: null,
      closeMenu: null
    },
    thursday: {
      openHour: null,
      closeHour: null,
      openMenu: null,
      closeMenu: null
    },
    ...
  }
```

This is what I've tried, I block the text :

```
openHour: null,
closeHour: null
```

and I have no idea what to do next to find and replace the text I've blocked.
I have search several questions on google but I found nothing, and don't even know what keyword to search. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common technique: use `:global` to match the lines you want. Then editing commands can be entered, for example, with `:normal`

```
g/closeHour/normal! oopenMenu: null,^McloseMenu: null
```

Here `^M` must be input as `^V<Enter>`

If your replacement text is already yanked into a register, you can put it as well:

```
g/closeHour/normal! ]p
```

(note: changing `normal! ]p` into `put` is possible but may require additional indentation fix, e.g. `='[`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this replace command:

```
:%s/\(openHour: null,\n\s*closeHour: null,\?\)/\1\r      openMenu: null,\r      closeMenu: null/
```

And you can even copy the indentation:

```
:%s/\(\s*\)\(openHour: null,\n\s*closeHour: null,\?\)/\1\2\r\1openMenu: null,\r\1closeMenu: null/
```

For more information see `:help :s`.
I can also explain the command if you want.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt using submatch:

```
/openHour\_.\{-}clos.*

:%s//\=submatch(0) . "\r          " . substitute(submatch(0), 'Hour', 'Menu', 'g')/g
```

First search using multiline search (non-greedy regex) `\_.\{-}`. We can reference our search simply by `//`. After that, we reinsert our search by using `submatch(0)` plus a newline with some spaces `"\r    "` then a modified version of our search with substitute.

The dot `.` is used in order to concatenate our string.

The [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4419802/matt) answer can be changed to:

```
:g/closeHour/exec "normal!oopenMenu: null, \<Enter>closeMenu: null"
```

Using double quotes we can use keypresses like `\<Enter>` instead of the classic `^M` that many users do not understand, thus it is more legible. I consider the second [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4419802/matt) solution the right one, it is easier to type and gets right to the point.

Instead of copying the desired text to any register, if it is already on the clipboard we can indicate that with: `"+]p`, thus it would be:

```
:g/closeHour/normal! "+]p
```